# TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function. I am using rest api and try to fetch data in react.js app using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

> This is my ReactPage with axios.Basically I want to use this data in data visualization but i didnt get the data. always "TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function." this error is showing.

**This is my ReactPage with axios. How to solve this issue and what is the cause of showing this error.. Thank you in advance for helping me out from this error**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
//import BootstrapTable from 'reactjs-bootstrap-table';
//import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
import './Getdata.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
//import Footer from './Footer';
import 'tachyons';

import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner'


class DynamicCharts extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            posts: [],
            loading: true
        }
    }
   // D:\myreactapps\reactyoutube\src\spinner.gif
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://covid19-india-adhikansh.herokuapp.com/states')
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({posts: response.data});
            this.setState({loading: false});
            //this.setState({loading: true});

        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    }


    render(){
       // const {posts} = this.state;
       //const { this.state.posts, loading } = this.state;
       let posts;
       if(this.state.loading){
           posts = <div className="tc">
                {/*<img src={ loading } />*/}
                <Loader
         type="Oval"
         color="gold"
         height={70}
         width={70}
         className="loader tc pt3"
         //timeout={3000} //3 secs

      />
               </div>
       }
       else{
           posts = <div><table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>State Name</th>
                   <th>Confirmed</th>
                   <th>Cured</th>
                   <th>Death</th>
                   <th>Total</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>

           <tbody>
               {this.state.posts.map(
                   data=><tr key={data.id}>
                           <td>{data.name}</td>
                           <td>{data.confirmed}</td>
                           <td>{data.cured}</td>
                           <td>{data.death}</td>
                           <td>{data.total}</td>
                   </tr>
               )}
           </tbody>

       </table>
       </div>

       }
        return(
            <div className="bg-white">
                {posts}
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default DynamicCharts;
```

Comment: what is printed from `console.log(response)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `this.setState({posts: response.data})` should be `this.setState({posts: response.data.state})`.

The data you're getting back is an object, with the root key being `state`, which holds the array (that can be mapped over).

Comment: It really helped me. I did't notice the api response structure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As andy mccullough suggested, you can console what the `posts` in state is. Seems like it has non-array like type. Also, saw that you want to use the destructuring method for `this.state`. Here is how it is done. You can try to add a bracket after `=>`.

```
render(){
    const {posts, loading } = this.state;
    //...
        <tbody>
            {posts.map(
                data => (
                    <tr key={data.id}>
                            <td>{data.name}</td>
                            <td>{data.confirmed}</td>
                            <td>{data.cured}</td>
                            <td>{data.death}</td>
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you mapping over object. replace your `this.state.posts.map` to `this.state.posts.state.map()`